# Debian: program in boot

Tags: debian

I just configured my new VPS with Apache, PHP, MySQL and ProFTPd. I wanted to install a smtp server, but I was advised to do a apt-get upgrade first. I did this, and I got up a blue screen where I could choose between two alternatives. It said something about GRUB 2 installer. I chose the alternative that was already selected, the topmost. I chose not to update the GRUB2, and use the old one that was installed.

Now, ProFTPd doesn't start in boot anymore. I have to /etc/init.d/proftpd start every time. How do I fix this? Should I have chosen to update GRUB2? Should I do apt-get upgrade again and try to do the same GRUB2 installer again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRUB have nothing to do with services. It just starts your kernel and then role of GRUB is finished, so there was some other modification that changed list of services that are starting at system boot.

Just add `proftpd` to services that start automatically. You could do this using `update-rc.d proftpd defaults`.

If you have now GRUB 0.9.x (GRUB Legacy) and you choose not to upgrade it to GRUB 2 there is no reason to change that decision. There are no changes in GRUB 2 that will make you real difference.

Comment: I have tried update-rc.d proftpd defaults, but it didn't work.

Comment: I did get output from the command, and it was not an error, however.

Comment: I checked /var/log/messages, but I didn't find anything there about ProFTPd.

Comment: And I didn't find anything in /var/log/proftpd/ eighter. It says that the ProFTPd server was shut down when I rebooted, and the log stops. It doesn't seem to be starting at all.

Comment: I did /etc/init.d/proftpd status, and it says ProFTPd is started in standalone mode, currently not running. This is 5 minutes after reboot.

Comment: I fixed it. It seems like there has been a faulty update, and they have released a new update to fix it. Because I did a new apt-get upgrade today, and it fixed the problems I've been experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Squeeze or later, as root:

```
# insserv proftpd
```

If using Lenny or earlier:

```
# update-rc.d proftpd defaults
```

Comment: Insserv proftpd didn'w work eigher.

Comment: I checked /var/log/messages, but I didn't find anything there about ProFTPd.

Comment: And I didn't find anything in /var/log/proftpd/ eighter. It says that the ProFTPd server was shut down when I rebooted, and the log stops. It doesn't seem to be starting at all.

Comment: I did /etc/init.d/proftpd status, and it says ProFTPd is started in standalone mode, currently not running. This is 5 minutes after reboot.

Comment: Uset `netstat -natp` and `ps -ef` to verify wether it in fact is or is not running.

Comment: Thanks for you help everyone! I'm going to set up everything from scratch, and this time I am not going to do a apt-get upgrade!

Comment: I fixed it. It seems like there has been a faulty update, and they have released a new update to fix it. Because I did a new apt-get upgrade today, and it fixed the problems I've been experiencing.